# Win Service not utilising CPU

Tags: cpu, windows-server-2016, windows-services

There's a CPU-bound Windows service (written in C#) running on a Win Server 2016 (8 core Xeon, 16 GB of RAM). Most of the time, the service does its thing (OCR for ducuments) and uses anywhere between 20% and 100% of the CPU. The service starts separate threads for the CPU-heavy operations.

Every now and then, however, the service starts using very little of the CPU (showing the process uses 0-1% and utilization of the CPU in general is just at 1%). The work finishes eventually, but it takes much longer (e.g. 30 mins instead of 2 mins). The only thing that helps in such a case is a restart of the system. Then the service/process starts using a lot more of the CPU.

Comment: What happens if you restart the service when it's slow?

Comment: @davidbaumann I get the "Windows could not start the service", possibly due to it timing out. It doesn't timeout after a reboot though.

Comment: Did you check wheter all processed were killed before restarting?

Comment: I didn't. I can try to check that next time it happens, but I don't see how that would be related to the service not using the CPU.

Comment: It's rather no OS problem, I guess it's a problem of the service instead.

Comment: I'm aware I could be, but I don't see why the cause can't be the OS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91983/discussion-between-davidbaumann-and-jdh).